# Javascript slide show of images

Tags: javascript

I am working on a code to create a slide show of image using javascript. I want the image to change continuously after a certain time interval and also when clicked. Here's what I did-

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src="1.jpg";
var image2 = new Image();
image2.src="1_1.jpg";
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src="1_1_1.jpg";
</script>



<img src="1.jpg" name="slide" width="200" height="200" onclick="changeimg()">
<script type="text/javascript">
var step = 1;

    function slideit() {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src");

        if (step < 3)
            step++
        else 
            step = 1

        setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
    }


    slideit();

    function changeimg()
        {
            slideit();
        }
    </script>

    </head>

    </html>
```

It's working fine but the speed increases every time I click on the image.. Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: This type of thing has already been accomplished with third-party libraries like jQuery... I would suggest checking that out... unless, of course you want to go through the learning process

Comment: Does your console output any errors?

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide more detail than "it's not working".  Is it getting an error?  Is the slide show not showing whatsoever?  Is the image not transitioning?

Comment: @ElGuapo I am new to javascript and have no idea about jquery! could you please share some links?

Comment: Here's a link with a few... http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slideshow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change image just needs to be calling the slideit function, and the timeout needs to be cleared. (Edit: Originally forgot about doubling timeouts)

```
var step = 1;
var timer;

    function slideit() {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src");

        if (step < 3)
            step++
        else 
            step = 1

        timer = setTimeout("slideit()", 2500);
    }


    slideit();

    function changeimg(){
            clearTimeout(timer)
            slideit();
        }
```

A better way to do this for future reusability my be to create an array of images, then using a similar logic to cycle.

Comment: Thank you! But the speed of the slideshow increases everytime click on the Image.

Comment: You have to set the "setTimeout" to a global variable..  then when someone clicks "changeimg" you need to call clearTimeout(that variable) and reset it in slideit().

Comment: @user3788040 I updated it, sorry about the initial rushed response.